# Decoding mail with python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to get a mail. Using imaplib, i get a bytes object. If i decode it with UTF-8, i get a message, split into two parts:

```
------=_Part_327394_2100449045.1588265266667
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

and

```
------=_Part_327394_2100449045.1588265266667
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

and neither of them looks like anything meaningful(probably because the mail contains non-latin symbols)
Trying to decode it with base64 didn't work - utf-8 can't decode anything after that.
So, how do I get the text?

Comment: Why are you parsing manually instead of using something like `email.message`?

Comment: This is exactly what email.message gives me